# Use one ajax call for different page and div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this code to make ajax call to change the content of div in main page without reloading the page :

```
function ajaxcall()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/create.php",
        success: function( returnedData ) {
            $( '#container' ).html( returnedData );
        }
    });
}
```

and I call it like that :

```
 <p><a  onclick="ajaxcall()" >Create</a></p>
```

The issue is very complicated because I have to call 4 pages in the same div :

```
create.hmtl ; update.html; delete.html ; read.html
```

Also I have 2 different forms in the same page that required the same thing, I mean I should do the same thing for the second form with another div "container-1",then I have 2 div for exmaple in create.html :

create.html :

```
 <div id="container">
     ....
 </div>

 <div id="container-1">
     ....
 </div>
```

So I call create.html everytime but different div for different form, the question is to use a minimum clean code to do all what I explained above?

**Edit**

To explain more my problem, I have 4 options (create/update/delete/read) with 4 pages, and in every page they are 2 div and 2 contents for 2 forms, I should change div content of every option(CRUD) for every form in webpage!

```
form -> ajax call content -> create.html -> div:container
form-1 -> ajax call content -> create.html -> div:container-1
form-1 -> ajax call content -> update.html -> div:container-1
```

Comment: We're talking about a div, then suddenly switch to forms. And only one clickable element is mentioned - are there more?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I make some changes to understand more what I mean...

Comment: save returned data somewhere, may be define a global object, AppData, have a property, data and everytym you call this ajax, just check that wthr AppData.data is having some value or not. If not, then call, else use that.

Comment: @kest, sorry I'm even more confused than before, but answers are starting to roll in so some people must have better imaginations than mine.

Comment: @Nielarshi makes a great suggestion.  Research "Scope and Closure" for this.  It enables you to basically declare a class and then instantiate it as an object.  The values of the object (populated through setter functions declared as properties) will persist over ajax call until the DOM is refreshed.  This can be very effective for your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add those as parameters to the function and make it like below

```
function ajaxcall(url, data, targetDivId)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data : data,
        success: function( returnedData ) {
            $("#"+targetDivId).html( returnedData );
        }
    });
}
```

For your scenario:

I assume that even the AJAX url may change as currently it's pointing to `create.php`. In case it's same then you can avoid tht parameter.

```
 <p><a  onclick="ajaxcall('/create.php', {} , 'container-1')" >Create</a></p>

 <p><a  onclick="ajaxcall('/update.php', object2 , 'container-2')" >update</a></p>

 <p><a  onclick="ajaxcall('/delete.php', object3, 'container-3')" >Delete</a></p>
```

Comment: I'm new with JS/ajax, can you explain more with pages I mentioned above (create.html, update.html..) and div names too....

Comment: Great, I have one more issue, I should send data or values of variables using "POST" to every pages, that mean for every page I should send different values and variables name?

Comment: again add that as parameter to the function and add `params` property to `$.ajax`

Comment: this can be change in inspect element of browser?

Answer (score 1):

Following mohamedrias' answer, if you also needed to process each alternate path in the CRUD use case differently, you can use global event handlers.

Don't handle when making the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data : data,
    success: function( returnedData ) {
    }
});
```

Do handle seperatley for each alternate path in CRUD

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        var query = settings.data;
        var url = settings.url;
    if (url.match(/create.php/) && query.match(/container1/)){
           $("#container1").find(".form-1").html( xhr.responseText );
    }
});
```

You should also notice that the selector in my example implies that "form-1" is a Class and not an ID.
IDs must be unique but Classes can occur many times.
Following this rule, if you wanted to reuse the same form for each alternate path you can do so by addressing discrete elements in the form using unique class names for each element.  The container Div must have a unique ID (as you have already done).  But you must give that element context by chaining the selectors to first select the div using ID and then select the element using class.

Comment: Can you do examples with name of 2 pages (create and update) and 2 div (container, container-1)

Comment: @mohamedrias gives you the common function to call for all Ajax calls.  include that in your DOM high enough to be available wherever you need to use it.  It will work on any page.  Then place the global event handlers where you need them to process the result for each use case.  All global event handlers get called for every response.  So you need to test if a response is applicable to the discrete handler.  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correcyly you want to provide an argument to the ajax calling function to apply the return content from "/create.php" to a different div.

```
function ajaxcall(id, path)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        success: function( returnedData ) {
            $("#"+id).html( returnedData );
        }
    });
}
```

And in html you can set the id like

```
 <p><a  onclick="ajaxcall(this.id, "/create.php")" >Create</a></p>
```

Comment: I'm new with JS/ajax, can you explain more with pages I mentioned above (create.html, update.html..) and div names too....

Comment: this can be change in inspect element of browser?

Comment: @AliRaza yep, you should be able to assign an event listener by adding it via the inspector

Comment: how it can b secure from the end user

Answer (score -2):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function(){

    var document = xhr.response;
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var container-1 = document.getElementById('container-1');
    console.log(container, container-1);

    // or

    // var containers = document.querySelectorAll("#container, #container-1" );
    //console.log(containers);

}

xhr.open('POST','/create.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader(
    'Content-Type', 
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);

xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Sorry, but your post does not answer the OP question at all!
Also, please refer to [this wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for how to post a good answer.